# How does the comma in line 2 translate to Fortran

Tags: fortran, gfortran

```
lat2: =ASIN(SIN(lat1)*COS(d/ER) + COS(lat1)*SIN(d/ER)*COS(brng))
lon2: =lon1 + ATAN2(COS(d/ER)-SIN(lat1)*SIN(lat2), SIN(brng)*SIN(d/ER)*COS(lat1))
```

The above code is part of the code to start with Lat1 and Long1, travel azimuth and distance to arrive at Lat2 and Long2.

I am trying to convert the equations to Fortran, but I do not understand what to do with the comma.  My current model is working for most test cases but is not correct when the distance crosses the 0 or 360 deg longitude line.  The Long2 error is in stead of say + 10 deg E I get 350 deg E.  I hope your model using the above equations handles the quadrant problem better.

Comment: Start reformatting your code as `code`.

Comment: Welcome, please read [ask].  Use tag [tag:fortran] for all Fortran questions so that Fortran people can actually see your question.

Answer (score 2):

ATAN2 is a Fortran [function of two arguments](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/ATAN2.html). It is a common function that exists in several other programming languages as well, probably also in the language you are copying your lines from. You should have told us which language is that!

The function  "computes the principal value of the argument function of the complex number *X + i Y*". The comma simply divides the first and the other argument.

Check, whether the language you are translating from uses the ATAN2 function in the same order for x and y as Fortran does. If not, switch the two arguments. Then simply call the Fortran function.

I do not understand this remark *"hope your model using the above equations  handles the quadrant problem better."* Is it just some left-over from your private communication?

Comment: While Vladimir states this very nicely and accurate, I just want to repeat something in different words: some programming languages define the function call as `atan2(x,y)` while others have `atan2(y,x)`. Do a cross-reference to ensure the correct behaviour.